# Creating a 2x2 subplot from one dataset as different graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a large census dataset I am working with and am taking different data  from it and representing it as a singular .png in the end. I have created the graphs individually, but when I try to add them to the subplots they get distorted or axis get messed up.

```
Current code:
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)

ax1.pie(df.data.valuecounts(normalize=True),labels=None,startangle-240)
ax1.legend(['a','b','c','d','e'])
ax1.axis('equal')

data2=df[['A']].dropna().values
kde=df.A.plot.kde()
binss = np.logspace(0.01,7.0)
ax2=plt.hist(hincp, normed=True, bins=binss)
ax2=plt.xscale('log')

ax3 = df.replace(np.nan,0)
ax3 = (df.groupby(['G'])['R'].sum()/1000)
ax3.plot.bar(width=0.9, color='red',title='Gs').set_ylabel('Rs')
ax3.set_ylabel('Rs')
ax3.set_xlabel('# G')

t = df[['p','o','s','y']]
ax4=plt.scatter(t.o,t.p,s=t.s,c=t.y, marker = 'o', alpha = 0.2)
plt.ylim(0, 10000)
plt.xlim(0,1200000)
cbar=plt.colorbar()
plt.title("this vs that", loc = 'center')
plt.xlabel('this')
plt.ylabel('that')
```

All four types of graphs should be displayed and not overlap.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you are getting and what you want. Pictures of your graphs might be useful.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the data you are trying to plot?

Answer (score 1):

You create Axes for each subplot but then you don't use them.
`ax1.pie(...)` looks correct but later you don't use `ax2`,`ax3`,`ax4`.

If you are going to to use the DataFrame plotting methods, just call `plt.subplot` before each new *plot*. Like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((6,3)))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
df.loc[:,0].plot()
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
df.loc[:,1].plot()
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
df.loc[:,2].plot()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Or use the Axes that you create.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((6,3)))

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3)

ax1.plot(df.loc[:,0])
ax2.plot(df.loc[:,1])
ax3.plot(df.loc[:,2])
plt.show()
plt.close()
```